# php loop through scripts array & remove item

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, loops

I have the following script in my cms page:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {

    SqueezeBox.initialize({});
    SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
        parse: 'rel'
    });
});

var j2storeURL = 'http://tours-international.com.gridhosted.co.uk/';

if (typeof (J2Store) == 'undefined') {
    var J2Store = jQuery.noConflict();
}


J2Store(document).ready(function () {
    J2Store('.j2storeCartForm').each(function () {
        J2Store(this).validate({
            errorElement: 'em',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().next('div'));
            },
            success: function (label) {
                //label.text('Ok').addClass('success');
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {

                j2storeAddToCart('addtocart', form);

            }
        });
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({});
});
```

I want to loop through the above and remove the following JS:

```
SqueezeBox.initialize({});

SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
    parse: 'rel'
});
```

Please advise easiest/smallest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to remove that part from a file???

If yes, then you can do the following:

1. Read the file into string `$file_str = file_get_contents('your_file_path')`;
2. Get the positions: `$pos_a = strpos($file_str, "SqueezeBox")` and `$pos_b = strpos($file_str, "var")`
3. Write this back: `substr_replace($file_str, "", $pos_a, ($pos_b - $pos_a));`

Good luck

Comment: Well, sort of - this is Joomla, so a plugin is injecting the SqueezeBox part into & building that script... so I need a bit of php to remove just the SqueezeBox bit, after it has been created

Comment: there is not an actual file, the javascript is being built & input into my template - so I want to add something to my template to remove that part

Comment: when you say "i wanna loop through", what do you mean. How do you exactly access this code...from where???

Comment: in my joomla template I have <jdoc:include type="head" /> - this pull's in bits & builds the head, including building that JS. So I just want to remove the SqueezeBox part of that JS after it has been built. So I thought about looping through the _scripts array and removing it from there.

Comment: what do you mean "scripts array"? If you can get a script from the array as a string => my answer still applies to it.

Comment: I think my answer helped you to solve your problem. You should accept it so that the question will be closed. People will not click on your question if there is not accepted answer.